# Infragisitcs Grid with a WebDialogWindow as an editable popup

Tags: c#, infragistics

I'm looking for some sample code or a link to a good site.

Does anyone have a sample of using an infragistics WebDialogWindow as an editable popup with an infra grid.  I'm targeting CLR 2.0 using c# preferably.  I would be updating a standard ADO.Net Datatable in a Dataset

I'm not a fan of the edit row template technique.

Thanks in advance!

Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty simple really.

1. Create a webform with an ultragrid and a web dialog.  Must include Script manager control.
2. Set the modal to true and window state to hidden on the web dialog.
3. Drop on the edit controls into the dialog along with an Ok and Cancel button.
4. Hook up the double click of the grid to set the window state to normal, and set the controls on the dialog to the values from the row clicked.
5. Stick code behind the Ok and cancel to deal with save and setting window state back to hidden.
6. Run it.

Final wee pointer.  Wrap the dialog up in a standard update panel (NOT warp panel) to improve the display if you are centring it.